# doxygen HTML output customzation

Tags: html, doxygen

I want to customize the HTML output of my doxygen-based help system. I tried reading the documentation but I didn't find anything that matches my requirement.

Is there a way I can list the function (along with the signature) in the left navigation pane of the doxygen HTML output? Currently there are many functions being listed but they all have the same name (with different arguments) It's confusing for someone to select the one they need.

I also checked the layout.xml file but couldn't make much of it.

Comment: At the moment there is no possibility to do this (as far as I know).The problem is that it might quite fast getting unreadable when there are a number of arguments. It would probably make more sense to "sqash" the functions together and jump to the first function in the documentation so he user can scroll on.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, Albert. I didn't think about the "squashing" part. Let me look into that. Do you have any tips on how I can do that? I'm new to doxygen so learning the ropes here. Any guidance will help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a solution for this, in doxygen there is no possibility for it (as far as I know), it would be a change in doxygen or you have to hack the result files.